# MVC3 : How to call A view from another controller from a different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor, partial-views, html.actionlink

I have to make a form consisting of several sub forms which may or may not contain grids.
For simplicity lets say i am using 2 models 
1. Applicant Detail : where the applicants basic information (Name, DOB, Gender) is placed.
2. Applicant Experience : where the applicants prev work experience details are being placed.

Now for organizing purpose i am thinking of making two different controllers Namely ApplicantDetail and ApplicantExperience and both will contain their respective functionalities. But as soon as the user enters his basic information i want the same view to call in the index view of ApplicantDetail which will have a grid and the user can enter his/her prev working details in the form of rows.

My basic question is, is there anyway that can i create single razor view which will contain the razor view of my ApplicantDetail as well??

Comment: @Molz ALi, was the answer that I provided satisfactory? Please either comment for clarification or accept.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is `RenderAction`.

Using `RenderAction` you can invoke controller/view within any view.

So if you had some razor view and second Controller and View combination, you could invoke it like so within the first view:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Action", "Controller2"); }
```

This can be useful when trying to modularize functionality.

See this blog post from Phil Haack for more details:
[Html.RenderAction and Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx)